# In Javascript IF-ELSE, IF Statement is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to work on verifying OTP. Here I have two components that are:

1. Textbox which takes input of OTP. id="txtOTP"
2. An Status Line (here i have used `<i>` tag) that shows status of verified OTP. id="statusLine"

I am using JavaScript for this purpose.

```
function checkOTP() 
{
  var OTP = "1234";
  var txtOTP = document.getElementById('txtOTP');
  var statusLine = document.getElementById('statusLine');
  var myOTP = txtOTP.value;

  if (OTP.value == myOTP) 
 {
    console.log('Entered in Valid OTP');
    statusLine.style.display = "inline";
    statusLine.style.color = "green";
    statusLine.innerHTML = "OTP Verified, Generating Your Pass and Redirecting to the Next Page... ";
    console.log('Exit From Valid OTP');
    return true;
  } 
  else if (OTP.value != myOTP) 
  {
    console.log('Entered in Invalid OTP');
    statusLine.style.display = "inline";
    statusLine.style.color = "red";
    statusLine.innerHTML = "Invalid OTP. Please Try Again";
    console.log('Exit From Invalid OTP');
    return false;
  }
}
```

As Per my code it should go to the if's scope if OTP is correct, and it should go to the else's scope if OTP is wrong. 
However, it always goes to the else's scope even though I am writing the correct OTP in the textbox. I have even tried this code without using if with the else statement (like else if() { } ).

Comment: remove value from OTP.value

Comment: You don't need a reverse condition in the `else if`. Just `if (...) ... else ...` will do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either change `myOTP` to a number or use double equals:

```
var myOTP = parseInt(txtOTP.value);
```

Or:

```
if (OTP == myOTP) {...}
```

Also note that you don't need `else if (...)` - just use `else {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

`OTP` is a `Number` but you check `OTP.value` in if/else if statements

```
function checkOTP()
            {
                var OTP = 1234;
                var txtOTP = document.getElementById('txtOTP');
                var statusLine = document.getElementById('statusLine');
                var myOTP = txtOTP.value;

                if(OTP === myOTP )
                {
                    console.log('Entered in Valid OTP');
                    statusLine.style.display = "inline";
                    statusLine.style.color = "green";
                    statusLine.innerHTML = "OTP Verified, Generating Your Pass and Redirecting to the Next Page... ";
                    console.log('Exit From Valid OTP');
                    return true;
                }
                else if(OTP != myOTP )
                {
                    console.log('Entered in Invalid OTP');
                    statusLine.style.display = "inline";
                    statusLine.style.color = "red";
                    statusLine.innerHTML = "Invalid OTP. Please Try Again";
                    console.log('Exit From Invalid OTP');
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yeah, not really, but close to the heart of the issue…

Comment: `OTP` is a number, but `myOTP` is a string, so this'll still fail…

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Its based on the comments and previous answers:

```
function checkOTP() {
    var OTP = "1234";
    var txtOTP = document.getElementById('txtOTP');
    var statusLine = document.getElementById('statusLine');
    var myOTP = txtOTP.value;

    if (OTP == myOTP) {
        console.log('Entered in Valid OTP');
        statusLine.style.display = "inline";
        statusLine.style.color = "green";
        statusLine.innerHTML = "OTP Verified, Generating Your Pass and Redirecting to the Next Page... ";
        console.log('Exit From Valid OTP');
        return true;
    }  else {
        console.log('Entered in Invalid OTP');
        statusLine.style.display = "inline";
        statusLine.style.color = "red";
        statusLine.innerHTML = "Invalid OTP. Please Try Again";
        console.log('Exit From Invalid OTP');
        return false;
    }
}
```

You needed to write `OTP` instead of `OTP.value` and you don't need and `else if` for the opposite. Just `else` will do.

Answer (score -2):

try adding a else statement after the else if since the syntax is :

```
if (condition1) {
  //  block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
} else if (condition2) {
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is true
} else {
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is false
}
```